# This Set-Cookie didn't specify a "SameSite" attribute and was default to "SameSite=Lax" - Localhost

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies, samesite

I'm a front-end developer working on an application where the `login/` response put a Session-Cookie on the client. The later request will be authorized since the user "logged in".

##### Starting from Chrome 80

All cookies without a SameSite attribute will be treated as if they had `SameSite=Lax` specified. In other words, they will be restricted to first-party only (server and client on the same domain).
If you need third-party cookies (server and client on different domains), then they must be marked with `SameSite=None`.

Restricted to first-party by default

```
Set-Cookie: cname=cvalue; SameSite=Lax
```

Allowed in third-party contexts

```
Set-Cookie: cname=cvalue; SameSite=None; Secure
```

For my application, I want the default behavior. My client and server running on the same domain in **production**. But in **development** I'm working from `localhost` (different domain).
Up until now, chrome had special flag under `chrome://flags` - **SameSite by default cookies**. I could Enable this flag on my development machine and the login passed. And in production, I didn't need this flag because I wanted the default behavior.

##### Starting from Chrome 91

The **SameSite by default cookies** flag was removed. This means that from this version I can't login into my app, without deploying it to production.

Does anybody knows how can I get the Session-Cookie while working from localhost. But still keeping the security of `SameSite=Lax`. If possible with client only changes, but if needed also with server changes.

[image: Chrome DevTools - SameSite error message]
*Chrome DevTools - SameSite error message*

[image: Chrome 80 Flags menu - These flags removed in Chrome 91]
*Chrome 80 Flags menu - These flags removed in Chrome 91*

#### Update

I tried to solve this by making the server use `SameSite=None` (development only).
This causes a different error: `Connection isn't secure`. This is because when using `SameSite=None` you are required to add the suffix `Secure` and of curse use HTTP**S** connection.
Secure connection has its own problems like having to pay for a Certificate in development.

Comment: Have you tried setting this flag `chrome://flags/#schemeful-same-site` to `Disabled` ?

Answer (score 5):

### As of Chrome v107 (Nov 2022)

I had a similar issue, spent a few hours digging, and what I found is that the only solution for Chrome is to make your front-end connection secure, ie `https` (using a proxy for instance): [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69908471/2076973)

An **alternative** solution is to use **Firefox** and set: `about:config` > `network.cookie.sameSite.noneRequiresSecure=false`. This allows `SameSite=None; Secure=false`

Comment: Indeed, one of our solutions was eventually using `https`. We just didn't want to pay for certificate for debugging env.

Comment: This solution is the only one that worked for me after hours and hours of searching. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not much relevant here but if anybody is using Create React App for a local app. Use https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/
That solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

##### Workaround: Downgrade Chrome

This is not a solution! just a temporary workaround for anybody like me how got his work halted due to this update.

- **Uninstall Chrome**
  Go to "Add or remove programs" and uninstall Chrome. Notice that user data like cookies and saved browser passwords may be lost.
- **Download Chrome v90** from [slimjet.com](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php), or from any other site. Then install Chrome.
- **Prevent auto-update** Chrome, according to this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483087/how-to-disable-google-chrome-auto-update) solution:
   open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update`
  rename the file `GoogleUpdate.exe` to `GoogleUpdate2.exe`.
  This will cause Chrome to not find the update package.
- **Update Flags** - Open Chrome and type: `chrome://flags`
  Search `#same-site-by-default-cookies` and **Disable** the flag

Comment: If you don't want to uninstall your current Chrome you can use Chromium dev build from cypress: https://chromium.cypress.io/mac/beta/90.0.4430.40. Also, thanks to that you can skip this "Prevent auto-update" step

Answer (score 3):

I have found a way to fix it and share it with everyone :-)

Description appears in the issues section:

> Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in
> cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.

[image]

In the Developer Tools section, go to the Application tab, and on the left side to Cookies:

> The cookie that you want to share with other domains, mark the Secure
> check and in Samesite put None. Update the site tab locally and you
> will be able to use the cookies that allow you to send through the
> domain of origin

[image]

I hope this brightens your day

Comment: As I already mentioned in a different answer that provides the same solution - this will not work! In the 'Application' tab you'll only see cookies that were successfully set. But in my case, the cookie failed to set, so it doesn't appear on that list

Comment: Sorry, but the solution is oriented so that third-party cookies can be consumed by other sites (for example localhost), that's what the Samesite attribute is based on. To set the development cookie on localhost, you must access the development environment in a browser tab and if the cookie is present, apply the modifications Samesite = None Secure-> check so that it can be consumed from the localhost tab

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we are able to also run our server locally on a different port and point our client app to that localhost address for development purposes.

For example, I have the client app running on `localhost:1234` and sending requests to a local copy of the server running on `localhost:5678`. This ensures that cookies are set successfully since the client and server are now "SameSite".

Admittedly, this is perhaps more of a workaround than a solution, but I hope it helps in the short term.

Comment: I can't run the server and client on the same machine during development

Comment: Since origin is different, you would need withCredentials on client & cors origin on server right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform "unsafe" CORS requests (which means performing a POST/PUT/DELETE request) you will need to modify the tomcat conf/context.xml file, to set sameSiteCookies to "none" instead of "lax".

```
    ...
<!-- default samesite cookies configuration, for CORS set sameSiteCookies to "none" and configure bundle for HTTPS  -->
<CookieProcessor sameSiteCookies="none" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem recently and found an easy solution that worked for me: `local-cors-proxy`: https://github.com/garmeeh/local-cors-proxy

Just install it with `npm i -D local-cors-proxy` and add a command to the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "proxy": "lcp --proxyUrl <REMOTE_DOMAIN> --port <PROXY_PORT> --credentials --proxyPartial= --origin http://localhost:<FRONTEND_PORT>"
}
```

`--proxyPartial=` is because by default `lcp` adds prefix `/proxy` to the path. Not sure why it's default.

if you need to send cookies, the following two commands are essential:
`--credentials` and `--origin http://localhost:<FRONTEND_PORT>`

if you omit `--origin` then `lcp` will set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `'*'` and browser will complain `Credential is not supported` or something like that.

Then you just run `npm run proxy` and access the server from  `http://localhost:<PROXY_PORT>`

Bersan already suggested to use proxy but in this case you don't make your frontend connection `HTTPS` and also don't need to set special values for cookie attributes `SameSite` and `Secure`.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the SameSite attribute manually to "None" + tick "Secure" inside the devtools for development.

That way you would not have to modify your production environment (keep the cookies as SameSite=Lax).

Comment: How to set cookie attribute in dev-tools?

Comment: In the 'Application' tab, go to 'Cookies' on the left hand side. Then you'll see all the cookies for the current site, select the site and double click the cookie entry you want to change in the list.

For stackoverflow it's like this:
Application -> Cookies -> ...stackoverflow....-> then there's a list of 5 cookies, double click on the SameSite entry of the last one, type 'None' - Done.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work. In the 'Application' tab you'll only see cookies that were successfully set. But in my case, the cookie failed to set, so it doesn't appear on that list