# ASP.NET core Azure AD authorization problem (chrome doesn't save cookies and makes loop requests)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add azure AD to my project and use [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles) tutorial as example.
With localhost all works fine, but after deploying a have such problem as loop redirects from chrome (version 91)[image: chrome 91 redirects]
 Also i get this problem using last version of opera and edge. While doing the same in safari and Firefox i didn't get any problems.
[image]
I think it might be a problem with samesite cookies, but i have already tried every one variant (none,lax,unspecified, strict). Also i noticed, that in Firefox in response Cookies i recieve "AspNetCore.Cookies and in Chome i'm not. 
 [image] 
 but in chrome it's only these one 
[image] 
Is anyone can help me with  that problem?

My StartUp file

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
                options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
            });
            
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;


            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
    "ClientId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: Since Chrome 91, the tags #same-site-by-default-cookies and #cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure have been removed from chrome://flags. You can right-click on the Chrome shortcut, Click "Properties". Add --disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure at the end of the "Target" attribute, and then restart the browser.

Comment: @NMSL thnx for the reply. This solution works (as previously in chrome 90) but it's a fix only for my chrome... What about another browsers and users with chrome?

Comment: Browser problem, maybe you have to lower the version. You can refer to this post：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67821709/this-set-cookie-didnt-specify-a-samesite-attribute-and-was-default-to-samesi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fix (it could be not the best, but it works well for me).
[MDN spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#samesitenone_requires_secure) says: "The warning appears because any cookie that requests SameSite=None but is not marked Secure will be rejected." That was my problem with browsers run over Chromium engine (Chrome/Opera/Edge). The default value was `CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest` i changed it to `CookieSecurePolicy.Always` :

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                
            });
```

Some screenshot of warning in chrome:

before
[image]

after
[image]